# Is there a way that with MLKit can detect injuries on skin

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, firebase-mlkit

Is it possible with MLKit to detect injuries on skin with a specific pattern, in order to determine if the injury is dangerous or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a capability of Firebase MLKit.  The list of things it can do is clearly outlined in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit#what_features_are_available_on_device_or_in_the_cloud).

Answer (score 2):

As Doug said: this is not a pre-made model that ML Kit comes with. I honestly doubt if such a model exists anywhere, as it sounds awfully specific.

That said, you can train a custom model, either directly with TF Lite, or with ML Kit's much simpler [AutoML Vision Edge](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/automl-image-labeling). In the latter case you'll need a good set of training images that you either have already pre-labeled or that you're willing to label yourself.

The [implementation path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/automl-image-labeling#implementation_path) for that is:

> 1. **Assemble training data**
>
>    Put together a dataset of examples of each label you want your model to recognize.
> 2. **Train a new model**
>
>    In the Firebase console, import your training data and use it to train a new model.
> 3. **Use the model in your app**
>
>    Bundle the model with your app or let the ML Kit SDK download it from Firebase. Then, use the model to label images on the device.